# Is a Ger first or almost last for assistance?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, priorities, ahavat-yisrael, friendship, chesed-kindness

The Pri Megadim in OC Siman 156 Ashel Avraham Sif-Katan 2 (it's a long piece) cites from the Rambam in Hilchos De'as Perek 6 Halacha 4 that the Mitzvah of Ahavas HaGer (loving a convert) is really 2 mitzvas "Aseh" (positive commandments.) The Rambam writes,

> אהבת הגר שבא ונכנס תחת כנפי השכינה שתי מצות עשה. אחת מפני שהוא בכלל
>   ריעים ואחת מפני שהוא גר והתורה אמרה ואהבתם את הגר. צוה על אהבת הגר כמו
>   שצוה על אהבת עצמו שנאמר ואהבת את ה' אלהיך. הקב"ה עצמו אוהב גרים שנאמר
>   ואוהב גר
>
> One mitzvah of because the convert is included in that of our friends
>   ("re'im") and another because he is a convert.

The Pri Megadim there writes that therefore there would be a "nafka minah" (difference) if someone came across a Yisrael (a born Jew) who needed help unloading something and a convert that needed help loading something. He writes that it's better to help the convert since there is an additional mitzvas aseh (positive commandment -- 2 altogether.)

In this being the case (according to the Pri Magadim) why then in Hilchos Tzedeka Yoreh Deah Siman 251 Sif 9 do we find that in the order of priority in who Tzedeka should be given a convert is almost the last one on the list (!?) Seemingly from this Pri Megadim he should be one of the first!

Answer (score 4):

The essay here

http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/729747/Rabbi_Ally_Ehrman/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D

cites a discussion of this very question in the sefer ואהבת לרעך page 245, but there doesn't seem to be a simple answer in that sefer. R. Ehrman proposes his own answer that the difference has to do with a machlokes on the status of a ger between the Rambam and Rashi and other rishonim, which manifests itself in these divergent halachos.